# Drupal 8 page editing

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, editing, page-layout

I have pages which are going to have lots of mixed content. To give an idea these are pages to show off an architect's work.

For example pages 1 will have
[image]

```
- 1 video (vimeo)
- a 2x2 grid of images (images are 50% page width)
- a 100% image.
```

Page 2 will have

```
- a 100% width image
- a 100% image 
- a 3x3 grid of images (images are 33% page width)
```

It continues like this where there is no real pattern but contains similar elements. It has to be flexible enough to include all the elements.

What is the recommended way to achieve this in drupal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a task for the new core Layout Builder module.

> It provides the ability to customize the layout of your content.

Dries showed a demo at DrupalCon Vienna 2017: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hx4EEzI7aNE

Here's also a brilliant article on that: https://evolvingweb.ca/blog/using-layout-builder-module-drupal-8

Comment: That's great, I used Expression Engine in the past and there was something very similar which I loved.